# metro ui css Проблема с border input при событии :focus

Tags: css, css3

Когда делаю клик по полю input(событие :focus), то оно становится где-то на 1-2px меньше. Какой стиль отвечает за это?

**UPD:**

```
              <div class="input-control text"  data-role="input">
                  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                  <button id="btnsearch" runat="server" class="button" onserverclick="btnsearch_Click1"><span class="mif-search"></span></button>
              </div>
```

P.S.: использую фреймворк [metro ui css 3.0](http://metroui.org.ua/)

Comment: напишите Ваш код

Comment: Тут важна сама суть, а не конкретный код. Как выключить вообще focus? Обнулить его. В этом суть вопроса.

Comment: его никак не обнулить... он есть и ничего с этим не сделаешь. Вам надо найти в CSS Вашего сайта где-то код, который изменяет поле на `:focus`. Developer tools любого браузера помогут. Если есть возможность, предоставьте ссылку...

Comment: нету возможности. А обнулить его как-то или что? Ну что бы визуально не было заметно, что он выделен. Даже если технически определенные процесы будут иметь место.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
#TextBox1:focus{outline:none;}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="TextBox1" name="test">
```

или для всех input:

```css
input:focus{outline:none;}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="test">
```

Comment: Перед тем как задать вопрос нагуглил этот способ. Он не работает.

Comment: он работает, м.б. для Вашего конкретного случая он не работает ввиду ряда причин.

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: у меня type='text' по-идеи нету

Comment: @DisguisePerceptron как раз таки для таких моментов и нужен Ваш код, чтобы не тратить время на предположения.

Comment: ок, виноват. учту на будущее

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30486/discussion-between-alex-and-disguiseperceptron).

Answer (score 1):

Итак, солюшн для тех, кто использует [метро ксс фрэймворк лайк виундоз 8](http://metroui.org.ua)

Когда мы используем штатный input, то при :hover бордер становится темным. Если использовать темный фон, то бордер на нем сливается и выглядит как крайне косячный текст-шедоу. За счет всего вышеперечисленного создается визуальный эффект *скукоживания* инпута. Рекомендую кастомизировать штатные стили в файлике metro.css